# Get formatting inconsistencies to generate warnings

Tags: resharper

I am using ReSharper 7.
I have set up my Formatting style, and I want Resharper to generate warnings (amber light in vs) when this style is not adhered to. For example if we do not follow K&R method bracing style I want to see the amber light.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate warnings for invalid style by installing [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/) for Resharper.
Whether StyleCop's default settings are suitable for you is another question.

Comment: so you cant do this purely with Resharper out of the box?

Comment: @jonho No, there is no way to do it using only ReSharper. StyleCop is your best bet.

Comment: @jonho: No unfortunately not, I have to agree with Dmitry